# How to access a Remote Desktop from a Virtual Machine set on a server?

Tags: server, port, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, portforwarding

Im using VirtualBox to set a Virtual Machine on a server.

I managed to access the remote desktop of the virtual machine from the remote desktop of my server but I'd like to forward the remote desktop of the virtual machine outside so I can access it like I access the remote desktop of my server.

The IP config of the server:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::857:1d78:27de:55ca%13
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 85.194.xxx.xxx
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 85.194.xxx.xx

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2410:d297:7e8c:e8ab%18
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

So when I connect via remote desktop to **85.194.xxx.xxx** I can start another remote desktop to **192.168.56.2:3389** (the Ip of the virtual machine in the VirtualBox Host-Only Network) but I would like to connect to it through **85.194.xxx.xxx** ip directly.

So I forwarded the **3389** port from **192.168.56.2** to **85.194.xxx.xxx:3395** using netsh

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=3389 listenaddress=192.168.56.2 connectport=3395 connectaddress=85.194.xxx.xxx
```

So it looks like :

```
    Listen on ipv4:             Connect to ipv4:

Address         Port        Address         Port
--------------- ----------  --------------- ----------
192.168.56.2    3389        85.194.xxx.xxx  3395
```

But when I try to connect to the remote desktop on **85.194.xxx.xxx:3395** it fails.
I turned off all firewalls to be sure that's not the problem here.

Any ideas why ?

Comment: Did you try to `telnet` to that IP / port pair? Do you have a firewall in the way (that is maybe blocking the port)?

Comment: I tried it doesn't respond. Also I tried **netstat -ano** on the server and the port is not open somehow although the RDP port on the virtual machine is open and listening

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found the solution. I wrote the IPs in reverse order

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=3389 listenaddress=192.168.56.2 connectport=3395 connectaddress=85.194.xxx.xxx
```

Should be

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=3395 listenaddress=85.194.xxx.xxx connectport=3389 connectaddress=192.168.56.2
```

But know I can't login no matter which account I use it keeps saying "Can't login"

Comment: OK the solution was that I had to use the server name as the domain name.